# "No module named" when unpickling data in Python 3.5 which was pickled using 2.5

Tags: python, pickle

I have the following three files:

test_class.py:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 13
```

write.py:

```
import sys
import pickle

import test_class

o = test_class.TestClass()
pickle.dump(o, sys.stdout)
```

read.py:

```
import sys
import pickle

import test_class

o = pickle.load(sys.stdin.buffer)
print(o)
```

Running read.py using Python 2.5 and piping the result to read.py using 3.7 produces the following error:

> c:\Python25\python.exe write.py | C:\Python37\python.exe read.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "read.py", line 6, in 
> o = pickle.load(sys.stdin.buffer)
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_class\r'

My question is: how do you unpickle 2.5 pickles correctly in 3.7?

Comment: You're writing in text mode and reading in binary mode.

Comment: Well, Python 2 writes in text mode by default. And pickle is supposed to be able to figure out the protocol version based on the contents. Does that mean I can't recover old pickle files created using 2?